# Запретить перенос формы по строкам

Tags: css3, html, css

Есть кусочек кода:

```
echo
'
<form>
<input type=text />
<input type=password />
<input type=submit />
</form>
'
```

Собственно проблема в том, что я не могу, в силу некоторых причин, запихнуть данную форму ни в таблицу ни в див, в которых собственно запретить перенос строк. Вопрос: как это сделать?

PS: Форма находится справа, соответственно, при размере экрана 1024*768 кнопка "отправить" уползает вниз, что ломает весь "дизайн". Хотя там до дизайна еще оч далеко(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
<form>&nbsp;<!--
--><input type=text />&nbsp;<!--
--><input type=password />&nbsp;<!--
--><input type=submit />&nbsp;<!--
--></form>
```

2)

```
form{white-space:nowrap;}
```

Comment: 2 - й вариант это css3? честно говоря, хотелось бы сразу рассматривать его, но "че то как то ссыкотно" в силу того, что юзвери(не все) очень любят свою кривую синию букву "Ё/Е" а еще и 7 версию, которая с пяточком/хрюшей/хпшкой 2002-го года выпуска комплектом идёт.

Comment: да я так подумал, кто любит Е пускай дальше любят и не возникают, ради них еще костыли изобретать...

Comment: Это CSS2. И ИЕ его тоже понимает